# How can I postpone my new job starting date because of surgery?

Tags: new-job

I accepted an offer from a job that I interned in the spring. The start date is october 2nd. They wanted me to have 150 credits to start and I had only 125 credits. I need to extend my starting date because I have to go for ACL surgery in August 2nd. what should I do? I am afraid I will not be able to finish the 25 credits on time. What should I do? I really worked so hard to get my dream job an I am troubled. Please advise me to what to do.

Comment: I've asked for start date extensions for personal or medical reasons before. If you need an extension on the order of a few weeks, I'm sure your potential employer would be more than happy to change your start date.

Comment: August 2 is a long time from now - is there a chance you can absolutely beat out the silly credits by then??? what's the situation on that ?

Answer (score 7):

> What should I do?

Tell your potential employer **the truth**.  They obviously like you, as they have worked with you in the past, and extended you an offer.  Your're not like other types of "*fresh off the street*" hires, they actually already have a **relationship with you**.  Don't risk it by being deceitful at this point.

Tell the truth, supply appropriate medical documentation to backup your story if necessary, and you should be good to go.  If your soon to be employer has an issue with this situation I am not sure you would want to work there anyway.

Comment: Right on.  "Tell your potential employer the truth".  I would just add, **literally tomorrow Thursday morning, at 0900:00 their time zone**.  Present it as an emergency crisis that has come up today, and you're telling them at 0900. "Ask for their help", say things like "How should I proceed?"

Comment: Agreed ACL surgery is common, and there is probably someone in your boss's family that underwent such surgery.  They will very likely be very sympathetic.